# How to get value and change outer variable inside event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have empty array. Need to fill it by clicking some links (only if value of current index is not filled already).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var genres_items = []; 

    $('.genre-fill-link').on('click', function() {
        var genre_index = $(this).data('g-index'); // get id of genre

        if(!genres_items[genre_index] { // want to check is this genre filled - get error, undefined variable 
            $.get('/get-genre-list/', {'genre-id', gener_index}, function(data) {  // if genre is not filled yet, want to get data by ajax
                gener_items[gener_index] = data;
            });
        }
    }

    console.log(genres_items); // get empty untouched array, even if links clicked
});
```

How to fill all elements of array **genre_items** (every element once by clicking **.genre-link**) ?

How to get values of this array in others handlers and callbacks afterwards?!

Javascript confused me =\  Please help

Comment: btw you wrote `gener_items[gener_index]` instead of `genre_items[genre_index]`

Comment: and at `console.log(genre_items)` it's perfectly normal that you get an "untouched array". the console.log part is executed before the callback of the $.get

Comment: 1)  Sorry, it's typo, I wrote this code manually here, not original copy-paste.  2) **genre_items** array _is undefied_ allready before ajax-callback, in **if** statement

Answer (score 0):

check my comments and try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 var genres_items = []; 

 $('.genre-fill-link').on('click', function() {
    var genre_index = $(this).data('g-index'); // get id of genre
    if(!genres_items[genre_index] { // want to check is this genre filled - get error, undefined variable 
        $.get('/get-genre-list/', {'genre-id', gener_index}, function(data){  // if genre is not filled yet, want to get data by ajax
            genres_items[genre_index] = data;
            console.log(genres_items);
        });
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Second part of question - How to get values of this array in others handlers and callbacks Afterwards?! If i click second, third and others of **.genre-fill-link** this checking will not work **if(!genres_items[genre_index])**.

Comment: But result must be `['jazz' => 'data_of_jazz...', 'rock' => data_of_rock...', 'reggie' => 'data_of_reggie...', ....]` .  Sorry for my english, if it wasn't understood

Comment: please post a jsfiddle or something similar with the precise line where you want to read `genres_items[genre_index]`